# Fedora fails to boot during upgrade from 25 to 26

Tags: fedora, boot, upgrade

I followed the command line instructions in [this](https://fedoramagazine.org/upgrading-fedora-25-fedora-26/) guide and ran the following commands:

```
sudo dnf upgrade --refresh  
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade  
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=26
```

After running `sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot` I selected the most recent Fedora option from GRUB (or rather let it automatically select it):   `Fedora (4.12.13-200.fc25.x86_64) 25 (Workstation Edition)`

Doing this I get a few errors like this and it fails to boot at all:

```
[       0.959745] ACPI Error: [DSSP] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170303/psargs-364)
[       0.959856] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SN.PCI0-SAT0.SPT5._GTF] (Node ffff97e80e170e60), AE_NOT_FOUND (20170303/psparse-543)
```

I've tried googling these errors but have not had much luck finding similar cases.

I can boot into bash by adding `init=/bin/bash` to the boot script and the disk Fedora is installed on seems to work fine there.

Comment: It's odd that the most recent available kernel is a *F25* kernel after update, not an F26 one.

Comment: I thought so too, but the guide does mention this: "With the dnf-plugin-system-upgrade package, your system reboots into the current kernel installed for Fedora 25; this is normal." Also note that this is *during* the upgrade. It has not yet completed since the upgrade should happen once the OS is loaded.

Comment: Oh, yes -- sorry, I didn't realize it had failed that early.

Comment: I'm not sure those errors are really the problem. Are there any other messages?

Comment: No, just more errors like the second one I wrote down. Do you have any tips for debugging this further? I can get to bash, so I can probably read some logs. Just not sure where to look.